# Background: url('') shorthand isn't retrieving my image in CSS

Tags: css

My image is called main-homepage-img.jpg, it is located in the img folder that is in my project folder along with index.html and style.css. I have tried `background: url('../img/main-homepage-img.jpg')` and plenty more variations, none working. How do I retrieve it? I have no issue doing it in HTML but I'd like to retrieve it via CSS.

Comment: looks like a relative url, The most common problem with relative urls is that it's not follow the file structure, as far as this goes no one can give you a straight answer, you have to double check your file structure with the relative url you're providing

Comment: Are both index.html and style.css in the same folder?  style.css isn't in css or styles?  If so, just understand that the image is relative to the css file, which would then make it `./img/main-homepage-img.jpg` or `img/main-homepage-img.jpg`

Comment: Can you post the URL that successfully retrieves the css file, and the URL that successfully retrieves the image? Like: `http://localhost/styles.css` and `http://localhost/img/main-homepage-img.jpg`?

Comment: @RobertMcKee So within the Project Folder, we have an img folder that contains the image, being main-homepage-img.jpg. We then have index.html and style.css (index.html and style.css are NOT in folders like the .jpg is in the img folder) so they're just simply sat in the Project Folder. I tried ./img/main-ho...jpg and /img/main-ho...jpg and neither retrive it.

Comment: @hellowordly123 I take it my solution didn't do the trick?

Comment: Hmm strange. background: url('./img/main-homepage-img.jpg'); has now worked. How strange it didn't register before. Thanks... all perfect now. @robertmckee how do I mark your answer as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file directory tree is structured how it sounds, it sounds you can just use `background-image: URL('./img/main-homepage-img.jpg');` and it should be able to find the image.

Comment: Yup. This didn't do the trick, unfortunately...

Comment: try using `url('img/main-homepage-img.jpg');` or `url('./img/main-homepage-img.jpg');`

Comment: url('./img/main-homepage-img.jpg'); has worked. Thanks!